# Excluding files from auto save (autoSave), in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have just picked up the Visual Studio Code, and am not very familiar with how the settings should actually be.

I have been trying to exclude a file type from **Auto Save** but I am not able to get this to work.
The auto save works, but the part which defines the exclusion does not work (It is basically suppose to exclude .liquid extension from autosave).

This is what I have done by far; in the **settings.json** file I added:

```
"files.exclude": {        
    "*.liquid": true
},
"files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
```

All other override settings I wrote int the .json file are working property, but this one does not.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently(2019-12-06), the answer is not. But you can follow the progress in develop.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42170

Answer (score 0):

This extension helps : [AutoSaveExt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oonsnnsk.vscode-autosave-ext&ssr=false#overview)

It enables to specify what all file extensions to auto-save.

How-to:

1. install it
2. keep the auto-save option in vscode to off
3. open settings.json
4. add below entry:

   ```
    "autoSaveExt": {
    "debounce": 999,
    "extensions": [".c", ".cpp", ".h"]
    }
   ```
5. reload window or relaunch vscode
6. now all files with extensions .c, .cpp and .h will be auto-saved after 999 ms of editing

Original reference : [wclr's comment @ Allow to set files.autoSave as language specific or folder setting
#42170](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42170#issuecomment-743500782)

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible, as of vscode v1.86 Stable Build, to use the `files.autoSave` setting in a language-specific (or language-overrideable) way.

So you can do this:

```json
"[liquid]": {                         // use the langage ID here
  "files.autoSave": "off"
},
```

Or perhaps this new setting in the Insiders Build is enough for you:

```
Files: Auto Save When No Errors
```

When that setting is enabled, only files with no errors will be saved.